# How to remove particular list from List in c#?

Tags: c#, list

I just want to retrieve a particular InventoryID and with the help of InventoryID, I want to remove specific list members that match the InventoryID.
For example, if the input is something like "INPOL". I want check this Id with arraylist and remove id,name,unit price and quantity that matches the input given by user("INPOL");

````
    {
        List<Inventory> inventories = new List<Inventory>();
        inventories.Add(new Inventory { InventoryId = "INDHS", InventoryName = "Office Chair", InventoryUnitPrice = 51, InventoryQty = 25 });
        inventories.Add(new Inventory { InventoryId = "INCDS", InventoryName = "Beds", InventoryUnitPrice = 105, InventoryQty = 12 });
        inventories.Add(new Inventory { InventoryId = "INING", InventoryName = "Dinning Tables", InventoryUnitPrice = 23, InventoryQty = 10 });
        inventories.Add(new Inventory { InventoryId = "INOPL", InventoryName = "Desks", InventoryUnitPrice = 155, InventoryQty = 7 });
        inventories.Add(new Inventory { InventoryId = "INWSZ", InventoryName = "Book Cases", InventoryUnitPrice = 80, InventoryQty = 34 });
        inventories.Add(new Inventory { InventoryId = "INQAB", InventoryName = "Coffee Tables", InventoryUnitPrice = 30, InventoryQty = 50 });

        return inventories;


    }
public void removeInventory(List<Inventory> inventories){
        Console.Write("Enter Inventory Id: ");
        InventoryId = Console.ReadLine();
        foreach(Inventory inventory in inventories){
            inventory.getId(InventoryId,inventories);
        
        }

    }
    public void getId(string? inventoryID, List<Inventory> inventories){
        if(inventoryID == InventoryId){
            inventories.Clear();
        }
    }```
````

Comment: You don't use an `ArrayList`(which is good) but  a generic `List<T>`

Comment: Thank you for your mention, sir. I'll note it hereafter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I can see, you use `List<T>`, not obsolete `ArrayList`; in case of `List<T>` you can try `RemoveAll`:

```
string InventoryID = "INOPL";

...

inventories.RemoveAll(item => item != null && item.InventoryId == InventoryID);
```

Comment: Thank you so much, sir. It resolves my issues. I look forward to learning more from you, sir. If I have any doubts in the future, kindly help me with them, sir.